# Where is this source for Kinetite powers?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, sith

If you check the [Kinetite page on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kinetite), it states that Sith masters used this power to flatten ferrocrete bunkers. Where is the canon source that states that?

Comment: I have no clue.  But I added a link and made minor typographical edits for you.  Hopefully that'll make it easier to get a good answer.

Comment: The very article states this is a non-canonical reference at the bottom. Since they don't have a source, I would take it with a grain of salt regarding its abilities to destroy ferrocrete bunkers. In A Splinter in the Minds Eye, the kinetite was very effective at attacking Darth Vader rendering him almost unable to fight. Anything that can do that should be considered dangerous, even if it isn't bunker-busting.